# complex regex help, convert html image link to cmd

Tags: string, replace, text-editor

hi have thousands of these regex links in html for images

```
<img src="image.png" alt="" style="zoom:55%;" />
```

I want to convert them to a quatro (.qmd) markdown links which will look like this

```
![](image.png){.r-stretch}
```

I have seen you can use a select in `"` but am unclear on how to only choose the `image.png` link but not anything in the documents in quotes. Also unclear is how to do the find and replace part (sed, VS code?)

Comment: Do you use any programming language ?

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. **Show us the actual code that you've tried**, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try searching

```
<img\s+(?=[^>]*\bsrc="([^>]*?)")(?=[^>]*\balt="([^>]*?)")?[^>]*\/>
```

and replacing it with

```
![$2]($1){.r-stretch}
```

You may check the test cases [here](https://regex101.com/r/V4JdIn/1)

This will also put anything in `alt` inside of the square brakets if there's any. If you don't want this behavior, you may just try [`<img\s+(?=[^>]*\bsrc="([^>]*?)")[^>]*\/>`](https://regex101.com/r/VAkpMx/1) with subsitution of `![]($1){.r-stretch}`.

Comment: Wow! I was starting to answer and you where faster. I just love your answer! I didn't know the **trick of the positive lookahead to capture some attributes in any order**. I'll note this down in my list of regex snippets.